# Eixir metaprogramming - defining macro available at compile time from within macro

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I am studying Elixir metaprogramming and I am toying around with making a `macro` that allows me to define REST resources. The interface would be like this:

```
defmodule Router do
  use Resources

  resource "cars"
  resource "animals"
end
```

I got as far as defining a module attribute using the `Module` module, but I can't get the following to work:

```
defmodule Resource do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      Module.put_attribute __MODULE__, :stack, [1, 2, 3]
      defmacro resource(name) do
        stack = Module.get_attribute __MODULE__, :stack
        Module.put_attribute __MODULE__, :stack, [name|stack]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The following does not compile:

```
defmodule Domain  do
  use Resource

  resource "foo"

  def run do
    IO.inspect @stack
  end
end
```

If I remove the resource line, it prints `[1, 2, 3]` correctly.

The `resource/1` macro is visible from `run/0`.

How could I get the code in Router to work, so that calling resource "xxx" pushes "xxx" to the stack on the `@stack` module attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the second `Macro` separately, not within the `__using__` macro. You can use the first macro to `import` Resource and define the initial `@stack`, so you can then use the `resource` macro in your Module.

You also don't need to call `Module.get_attribute` and `Module.put_attribute`, and just use `@stack` everywhere.

Try this:

```
defmodule Resource do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      import Resource
      @stack [1,2,3]
    end
  end

  defmacro resource(name) do
    quote do
      @stack [unquote(name) | @stack]
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `Domain.run` should now give you `["foo", 1, 2, 3]`. You should also go over the Official guide on building your own [Domain Specific Languages](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/domain-specific-languages.html#the-test-macro) in Elixir.